# GNOME Tweak Tool does not open anymore

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

I have used ubuntu 20.04 since the day it was published and everything worked nice, but recently (I did not notice exactly when) GNOME Tweak Tool cannot be launched. I tried to `remove --purge` and reinstalling it but it did not help.

When I try opening it in the Terminal I get a strange response:

```
Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Comment: when I try opening it in the terminal I get a strange response:
Failed to register: Timeout was reached

Comment: From somewhere this was suggested `killall gnome-tweaks`, see if it makes any difference.

Comment: surprisingly there was a process of gnome-tweaks in top output, and yes! it did work. thank you :)

Comment: Please do not add "[SOLVED]" to the title. Ask Ubuntu is not like other forums. The right way to indicate you've found a working solution is by ["accepting" the most helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) which you already did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used `top` to see the open processes and yes, there was a `gnome-tweaks` running.

So I used `killall gnome-tweaks` to close it, it did work and I now have my `gnome-tweaks` back

Comment: This solved my troubles on Ubuntu 20.04!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I couldn't kill `gnome-tweaks` with `killall`, so I killed it by PID with `kill`.

After that, I started `gnome-tweaks` over the command line and it throwed an `UnicodeDecodeError` error. This seems to be a [known issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/issues/129). To fix that, you have to find out which file inside `~/.config/autostart` is causing the error.

In my case the culprit was `org.moson.matray.desktop` and others reported `vivaldi-stable.desktop`. But probably you have to find that out on your own like this:

Move all files from `~/.config/autostart` to another folder. `gnome-tweaks` should start now. To find the culprit, copy them back on by one and each time start `gnome-tweaks`, until it throws the error again. To fix it, remove that file or fix its encoding.